# Facebook connect for Blackberry Application

Tags: facebook, blackberry-simulator

I am using the Blackberry Facebook sdk from http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/.

The PDF included in the zip file says that attach/include the two .jar files in the Project using eclipse and then use the methods to get user information from facebook.

Including the jar files is fine but when i call the methods and try running the app i get a Run time exception " java.lang.noClassDefFoundError ". No compilation error but a runtime error. I have tried cleaning up the BB 9900 Simulator but it doesn't work. I am pasting the code that causes the runtime exception.

```
 String NEXT_URL = "http://m.facebook.com/login.php";
 String APPLICATION_ID = "318512824926003";
 APPLICATION_SECRET = "e0e532b55a4586ec2fb0eddf4eed12b1";
 String[] PERMISSIONS = Facebook.Permissions.USER_DATA_PERMISSIONS;
 ApplicationSettings as = new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, PERMISSIONS);
  Facebook fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);
```

Inserting the above code causes the runtime exception. Many users have told that this works but have not provided a simple and end solution. So please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Guys, i got a succcess in implementing FB connect using this link : https://github.com/chrismoos/facebook-bb-sdk/tree/master/src. I used the class files given and was able to authenticate and retrieve users info. Now the crazy part is, email id of user is not given using the methods available in the class files. Can someone help me retrieve email id of user.

Comment: great.. i got it working.. I retrieved the **email id** of the FB user by add a parameter LoginScreen.java file. 

Parameter added : "email"

"http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=publish_stream,offline_access,**email**&redirect_uri=" + pfbc.getNextUrl() + "&response_type=token&display=touch&client_id=" + pfbc.getApplicationId()

Guys if u need any help integrating FB Connect to your BB App please email me at alvin.chettiar@hotmail.com . Il be glad to help. I know the head banging that i went through to get this sorted. I would love to give a proper solution..

Thanks.

Regards,
Alvin

Answer (score 0):

great.. i got it working.. I retrieved the **email id** of the FB user by adding a parameter to LoginScreen.java file.

Parameter added : "email"

"http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=publish_stream,offline_access,***email***&redirect_uri=" + pfbc.getNextUrl() + "&response_type=token&display=touch&client_id=" + pfbc.getApplicationId()

Guys if u need any help integrating FB Connect to your BB App please email me at alvin.chettiar@hotmail.com . I will be glad to help. I know the head banging that i went through.